# android intent call without asking

Tags: cordova, android-intent, zxing, barcode-scanner

My phonegap app using zxing barcode scanner. I aso install a demo app (barcodescanner) from zxing. Now, in my phonegap app, when I call a barcode scanner, android ask me choose which app to do this action (my app and zxing barcodescanner). How to avoid this? I don't want android asking my user like this

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed any code, by default Zxing registers with the following intent.

```
<action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />
```

You can change this to make it more specific to you application by doing following changes.

```
// in BarcodeScanner.java plugin file

public void scan() {
    // changed to custom intent
    Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.dhaval.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.ctx.startActivityForResult((Plugin) this, intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
}


public void encode(String type, String data) {
    // changed to custom intent
    Intent intentEncode = new Intent("com.dhaval.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE");
    intentEncode.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
    intentEncode.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);

    this.ctx.startActivity(intentEncode);
}
```

In your application AndroidManifest.xml file, change intent filter string to your custom string used in BarcodeScanner.java file above

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.dhaval.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/share_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.dhaval.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: For anybody that runs into the same issue I did - there is one more place you need to rename the intent - in the LibraryProject go to src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java look for "public static final String ACTION" and change it to your new intent name.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setPackage()` on the `Intent` that you send to direct it to only one possible application. Here you would set to `"com.google.zxing.client.android"`.